# Javascript constructor to factory

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor

Pretty simply, I have this:

```
var x = new MessageQueue(config);
```

And for a unit test I want to be able to pass a `connector` method so I can call this:

```
var x = connector(config);
```

I don't want to force the unit test writer to have to remember to only pass new-able things.  So my code looks like this right now:

```
var x = config.connector || function(config) { return new MessageQueue(config); }
```

Is there any javascript utility function or one-line way to wrap this `new` up inside another function? I haven't found anything so far but it would be nice, and it seems given how many options there are for `bind` and `apply` and `call` that I could do this.

Don't think you can quite get it with `apply` since even if you `apply` against a new object, there's funny business rules for what's returned at the end of a new call.

Comment: Funny thing... A book I just read recommended creating a first-class function to do exactly this and use that first-class function to return the new objects.

Comment: *"Is there any [...] one-line way to wrap this new up inside another function?"* Didn't you just write that?

Comment: @FelixKling yeah, but I'll have to write it *every time*. Possibly duplicating what already exists in the standard API.

Comment: There is no built in or standard way to do this. I mean, you can easily create your own helper function and then just import it.